# How to track in pycharm using pyautogui

Tags: pycharm, pyautogui

I seem to have a problem using pyautogui by importing it error occurs saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui' what do i do

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the library from Pypi using the terminal (in the bottom of Pycharm) :

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Comment: i did it, updated and still have the same error :(

Comment: Using Pycharm tool may solve your problem : 

Follow this way : View | Tool Windows | Python Packages

And then install pyautoguy

Comment: only options after tool windows that i have are Project Favourites TODO Structure Services Event log Python Console and Treminal

Comment: maybe there is another option to track my mouse position not using pyautogui?